# Search in mongoid/mongo console not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, activerecord, mongoid, mongodb-query

I have some **fields** in my model `category`, `tags` which contains lots of `text`

Take the following data for example,
It should be found by these search keywords `Iron`, `Pig`, `Academic Data`

```
{
    "_id" : "M0130AUSM561NNBR",
    "name" : "Pig Iron Production for United StatesMonthly, Not Seasonally Adjusted,  ",
    "categories" : [
        "Production of Commodities",
        "NBER Macrohistory Database",
        "Academic Data"
    ],
    "tags" : "[\"iron\", \"metals\", \"nber\", \"production\", \"monthly\", \"nation\", \"usa\", \"nsa\"]",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-12-30T03:38:13.954Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2014-12-30T03:38:13.954Z")
}
```

I tried to query by `Indicator.text_search("Pig")`

But I got nothing

```
irb(main):005:0> Indicator.text_search("Pig")
=> #<Mongoid::Contextual::TextSearch
  selector:   {}
  class:      Indicator
  search:     Pig
  filter:     {}
  project:    N/A
  limit:      N/A
  language:   default>
```

Tried to search with `Indicator.any_of({ :text =>  /.*Production.*/ })`

I still got nothing.

```
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"$or"=>[{"text"=>/.*Production.*/}]}
  options:  {}
  class:    Indicator
  embedded: false>
```

Tried to search in mongo console, still not works (nothing in the result)

```
    > db.indicators.find({"title": /.*Production.*/})
    >
```

#### Model : Indicator.rb

```
class Indicator
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
  # include Mongoid::Search
  field :id, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :category, type: String
  field :tags, type: String
  # search_in :tags, :category
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell query

```
db.indicators.find({ "title" : /.*Production.*/ })
```

won't find any documents because there is no `title` field, according to your sample documents. Is a text index defined?

```
db.indicators.ensureIndex({ "name" : "text", "categories" : "text", "tags" : "text" })
```

Additionally, `tags` is a string that resembles an array of strings - is that what you want? Or do you want n array of strings? I'd think you want

```
"tags" : ["iron", "metals", "nber", "production", "monthly", "nation", "usa", "nsa"]
```

rather than

```
"tags" : "[\"iron\", \"metals\", \"nber\", \"production\", \"monthly\", \"nation\", \"usa\", \"nsa\"]"
```